# Recording Raw sound by Web API Audio

Tags: audio, webapi

Can the Web API Audio enable to record raw sound from an external sound card?
Can it have the same quality as the sound recorded by a recorder (Zoom f1, f2) for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like it only supports the following formats:

- Opus (lossy compression)
- PCMA & PCMU (narrow band, for speech)

See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/WebRTC_codecs#supported_audio_codecs) and the [standard it references](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7874#section-3).